# Android - Align Layout above the keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/view_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/marca"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/marca" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/marca"
            android:id="@+id/form_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView style="@style/separador" />

            <LinearLayout style="@style/box_field">

                <ImageView
                    style="@style/icon_field"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_usuario" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/usuario"
                    style="@style/edit_field"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_usuario"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView style="@style/separador" />

            <LinearLayout style="@style/box_field">

                <ImageView
                    style="@style/icon_field"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_senha" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/senha"
                    style="@style/edit_field"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_senha"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSend"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView style="@style/separador" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/botao_entrar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="#009999">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/Entrar"
                    android:textColor="#cccccc"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/msg_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_msg_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#233246" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My manifest looks like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

What I need is this that when you open the keyboard, resize my screen, that is, the entire layout is above the keyboard. Does anyone know any way to do this?

Comment: try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

Comment: Do you want the keypad to overlay on your layout?

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia don`t, I want my layout above keypad

Comment: you have to try by changing the properties of android:windowSoftInputMode  based on your layout  "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" ?